# How to get a id value of tables in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to get a unique, identical value of a table?
For example, if there are tables like 't_aa', 't_bb', 't_cc', I want a result like below.

```
id   |   table_name
-------------------
1    |    't_aa'
2    |    't_bb'
3    |    't_cc'
```

What I exactly want is to get a specific, and unique number from the name of tables.

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables;

-- or

SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables;
```

but this doesn't provide any identical numbers to me.

I hope there is some way to get results like above by using some lines of query,
but if I really have to make a new table for this, that could be okay as an alternative.

please help me, thank you

-- edit
I need numbers because I will use it as an advisory lock key for some reasons.

Comment: Why do you need a number? A fully qualified table name that includes the schema will be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ThIs is it:

```
    SELECT table_name,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
       ORDER BY table_name
    ) as id FROM information_schema.tables;
```