# PSQL Query to list last n number of table names

Tags: sql, postgresql, terminal, psql

I want to get the list of **last n number** of  table names present in a schema in a particular database. The problem is there are lots of tables and is not convenient to scroll through all of them to reach the end. Is there a way I can use something equivalent of **tail -f**  command which is used to look at the recent updates in a log file.

I have tried something like **tail -f \dt** in the current schema. But doesn't work.

Comment: `order by table_name desc fetch first n rows only`.

Comment: @Kartik Hegde you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74287368/how-to-get-a-id-value-of-tables-in-postgres/74287518#74287518

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is it:

```
select * from (
SELECT table_name,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
       ORDER BY table_name desc
    ) as id FROM information_schema.tables
) where id<=5;
```

for example you can replace 5 with any number.

Comment: This can be simplified using `order by table_name desc fetch first n rows only`. No need for a window function or derived table.

Answer (score 0):

It should be with alias name in sub query

```
select * from (
SELECT table_name,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
       ORDER BY table_name desc
    ) as id FROM information_schema.tables
)x where id<=5;
```

Answer (score 0):

In unix terminal. You can do following.
ending 5 rows. 7 = 5+ row(`table rows count`) + 1(empty new line).

```
/usr/local/pgsql15/bin/psql test15 -c '\dt' | tail -7
```

print first 5 row.You can

```
/usr/local/pgsql15/bin/psql test15 -c '\dt' | head -8
```

8 = 5 + following 3 meta row.

- row("`List of relations`")
- row( `Schema |          Name           |       Type        | Owner`)
- row(`--------+-------------------------+-------------------+-------`)

Comment: is 'test15' name of the database that you have used?

Comment: @KartikHegde yes. replace all the connect info to your credentials.